# How to Pause/Resume an asynchronous worker, without incurring memory allocation overhead?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, valuetask, nito.asyncex, ivaluetasksource

I have an asynchronous method that contains an endless `while` loop. This loop is paused and resumed frequently by the main thread of the program. For this purpose I am using currently the [`PauseTokenSource`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/cooperatively-pausing-async-methods/) class from the [Nito.AsyncEx](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nito.AsyncEx/) package:

```
private readonly PauseTokenSource _pausation = new();

private async Task StartWorker()
{
    while (true)
    {
        await _pausation.Token.WaitWhilePausedAsync();
        DoSomething();
    }
}
```

This works pretty well, but I noticed that around 100 bytes are allocated each time the `PauseTokenSource` is paused and resumed. Since this happens many times per second, I am searching for a way to eliminate this overhead. My idea is to replace the `PauseTokenSource` with a home-made pausation mechanism that has a `WaitWhilePausedAsync` method that returns a [`ValueTask`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/understanding-the-whys-whats-and-whens-of-valuetask/) instead of `Task`. To make the implementation allocation-free, the `ValueTask` should be backed by something that implements the [`IValueTaskSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.sources.ivaluetasksource) interface. Here is my current (failed) attempt to implement this mechanism:

```
public class Pausation : IValueTaskSource
{
    private ManualResetValueTaskSourceCore<bool> _source;
    private bool _paused;

    public Pausation() => _source.RunContinuationsAsynchronously = true;

    public void Pause()
    {
        _paused = true;
        _source.Reset();
    }

    public void Resume()
    {
        _paused = false;
        _source.SetResult(default);
    }

    public ValueTask WaitWhilePausedAsync()
    {
        if (!_paused) return ValueTask.CompletedTask;
        return new ValueTask(this, _source.Version);
    }

    void IValueTaskSource.GetResult(short token)
    {
        _source.GetResult(token);
    }

    ValueTaskSourceStatus IValueTaskSource.GetStatus(short token)
    {
        return _source.GetStatus(token);
    }

    void IValueTaskSource.OnCompleted(Action<object> continuation, object state,
        short token, ValueTaskSourceOnCompletedFlags flags)
    {
        _source.OnCompleted(continuation, state, token, flags);
    }
}
```

My `Pausation` class is based on the [`ManualResetValueTaskSourceCore<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.sources.manualresetvaluetasksourcecore-1) struct, which is supposed to simplify the most common `IValueTaskSource` implementations. Apparently I am doing something wrong, because when my worker `await`s the `WaitWhilePausedAsync` method, it crashes with an `InvalidOperationException`.

**My question is:** How can I fix the `Pausation` class, so that it works correctly? Should I add more state beyond the `_paused` field? Am I calling the `ManualResetValueTaskSourceCore<T>` methods in the wrong places? I am asking either for detailed fixing instructions, or for a complete and working implementation.

**Specifics:** The `Pausation` class is intended to be used in a single worker - single controller scenario. There is only one asynchronous worker (the `StartWorker` method), and only one controller thread issues `Pause` and `Resume` commands. Also there is no need for cancellation support. The termination of the worker is handled independently by a `CancellationTokenSource` (removed from the above snippet for brevity). The only functionality that is needed is the `Pause`, `Resume` and `WaitWhilePausedAsync` methods. The only requirement is that it works correctly, and it doesn't allocate memory.

A runnable online demo of my worker - controller scenario can be found [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NjNxOR).

Output with the `Nito.AsyncEx.PauseTokenSource` class:

```
Controller loops: 112,748
Worker loops: 84, paused: 36 times
```

Output with my `Pausation` class:

```
Controller loops: 117,397
Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.ManualResetValueTaskSourceCore`1.GetStatus(Int16 token)
   at Program.Pausation.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetStatus(Int16 token)
   at Program.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<<Main>g__StartWorker|0>d.MoveNext()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you're misunderstanding `Reset`. `ManualResetValueTaskSourceCore<T>.Reset` is nothing at all like `ManualResetEvent.Reset`. For `ManualResetValueTaskSourceCore<T>`, `Reset` means "the previous operation has completed, and now I want to reuse the value task, so change the version". So, it should be called after `GetResult` (i.e., after the paused code is done awaiting), not within `Pause`. The easiest way to encapsulate this IMO is to `Reset` the state immediately *before* returning the `ValueTask`.

Similarly, your code shouldn't call `SetResult` unless there's a value task already returned. `ManualResetValueTaskSourceCore<T>` is really designed around sequential operations pretty strictly, and having a separate "controller" complicates things. You could probably get it working by keeping track of whether or not the consumer is waiting, and only attempting to complete if there is one:

```
public class Pausation : IValueTaskSource
{
    private ManualResetValueTaskSourceCore<bool> _source;
    private readonly object _mutex = new();
    private bool _paused;
    private bool _waiting;

    public Pausation() => _source.RunContinuationsAsynchronously = true;

    public void Pause()
    {
        lock (_mutex)
            _paused = true;
    }

    public void Resume()
    {
        var wasWaiting = false;
        lock (_mutex)
        {
            wasWaiting = _waiting;
            _paused = _waiting = false;
        }

        if (wasWaiting)
            _source.SetResult(default);
    }

    public ValueTask WaitWhilePausedAsync()
    {
        lock (_mutex)
        {
            if (!_paused) return ValueTask.CompletedTask;
            _waiting = true;
            _source.Reset();
            return new ValueTask(this, _source.Version);
        }
    }

    void IValueTaskSource.GetResult(short token)
    {
        _source.GetResult(token);
    }

    ValueTaskSourceStatus IValueTaskSource.GetStatus(short token)
    {
        return _source.GetStatus(token);
    }

    void IValueTaskSource.OnCompleted(Action<object> continuation, object state, short token, ValueTaskSourceOnCompletedFlags flags)
    {
        _source.OnCompleted(continuation, state, token, flags);
    }
}
```

I fixed some of the obvious race conditions using a mutex, but I can't guarantee there aren't more subtle ones remaining. It will certainly be limited to a single controller and single consumer, at least.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, this fixes the problem and works great! You are right, I was confused about the purpose of the `Reset` method. :-)

Comment: I updated my demo with the correct `Pausation` implementation. [Link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IMaT1s). It doesn't crash, and it produces the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You may have misunderstood the purpose of `ValueTask`. Stephen Toub breaks down why it was introduced here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/understanding-the-whys-whats-and-whens-of-valuetask/

But the most relevant bit of information is that `ValueTask` does not allocate **iff** the asynchronous method completes synchronously and successfully.

If it does need to complete asynchronously, there is no getting around needing to allocate a `Task` class due to the state machine in the background. So this may need another solution entirely.

Comment: Hank I am aware of this article. You can read [further below](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/understanding-the-whys-whats-and-whens-of-valuetask/#valuetask-tresult-and-asynchronous-completion) that: *"However, when working on very high-throughput services, we still care about avoiding as much allocation as possible, and that means thinking about reducing and removing allocations associated with asynchronous completion paths as well."*

Comment: You are correct. Apologies. You got an answer from the man himself though!

Comment: Yep, and it's a great answer! Not many people can appreciate it though, because the concept of the `IValueTaskSource`-backed `ValueTask`s is pretty esoteric.

Comment: It's definitely sent me down a rabbit hole of exploring the usage of `IValueTaskSource` in the runtime repo.